# What is the statistical power of a test when the true population mean is unspecified?

Tags: self-study, statistical-power

I have been given the following homework problem:

> To improve the reading scores of its students, a school district randomly selects 50 students to participate in a new program. The mean reading score for all students was 49. The students using the new program had an average score of 52.6 and a standard deviation of 5.1. If α = 0.05, what is the power to detect that scores really do increase to 52.6 using the new program?

I can only see how statistical power can be computed if the problem also provides me with some "true" mean score $\mu_t$ for students in the new program. Is it easy to see what the flaw in my thinking could be?

Comment: We welcome questions like these, but we treat them differently: we provide hints to help you answer the question yourself. Please read the self-study tag [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for more information.

Comment: That's correct. You are trying to detect a difference between the true mean (in this case 49) and the observed mean. In general, the true mean will be implicit, for example, an effect size of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several [types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power#A_priori_vs._post_hoc_analysis) of power analysis.  You are thinking about the most common type, *a-priori* power analysis.  But other types exist, and may be appropriate for your problem.